# No module named mock with python 3.2

Tags: python, python-3.2

I can import mock with python 2.7, 3.3 and 3.4 but when using 3.2 I get the following import error.

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
>>> from mock import patch

Python 3.2.5 (default, Aug 25 2015, 09:22:32) 
>>> from mock import patch
...
ImportError: No module named mock
```

How can I resolve this for Python 3.2?

Comment: In your virtualenv, `pip install mock`.

Comment: `This is because unittest.mock  is new in version 3.3`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the module is not installed for python3.2.
You have to install it. If you have `easy_install` or `pip` installed for that interpreter you should be able to simply do:

```
easy_install3.2 mock
```

or:

```
pip3.2 install mock
```

If you are using a virtual environment you may first need to activate it.
*If* you activate a virtual environment for the python3.2 interpreter you shouldn't need to specify the version of `pip`, so `pip install mock` should work)

---

Note that this module was integrated in the standard library as [`unittest.mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) from python3.3+. So in python3.3+ you can `from unittest.mock import patch` and this wont require any installation.

Comment: The issue is actually with tox and specifically python3.2, but annoyingly i submitted before completing the question.  Given the question this is the right answer though ;)